# Cannot read dynamic properties with FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, dynamic, xunit, fluent-assertions

I am using XUnit and fluentassertions in c sharp for my unit tests. Below is where I get a dynamic type, convert a dynamic object to that dynamic type and try to do an assertion:

```
        var dynamicType = Type.GetType(...);

        dynamic? myObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(myJSONData, dynamicType);

        myObject!.Products!.Should().NotBeNull();
```

If I debug it, myObject does have the required properties and values, however c sharp and fluentassertion throw this error:

```
  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : 'xxxxx.Products' does not contain a definition for 'Should'
```

Is it possible to do the comparison or did I miss out anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a limitation in .NET.
It does not support extension methods for `dynamic` objects.

A workaround is to cast `myObject` into an `object`, such that the appropriate overload of `Should` can be determined at compile time.

Some related issues:

- https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/234
- https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/473
- https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/1493
- https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/1738

Comment: This worked when I tested it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to do it, just add (object) cast in front of the assert if your object is dynamic.

```
(object) myObject!.Products!.Should().NotBeNull();
```

You need to import System.Object.